# SenseNet versioning - content locking

Tags: sensenet

Trying to understand SN content versioning;

- What is the purpose of "LockType", "LockToken" in "Nodes" table and what are their possible values?
- What is the difference between "LockDate" and "LastLockDate"?

Many thanks.

Comment: For content versioning there is a separate table (Versions) that stores content version info (e.g. who created that version, major and minor version number of course, etc.). These "lock" columns in the Nodes table are only for supporting th Open in Office feature (they are updated by Word, when you open a file directly in Office).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following fields are used by older MS Office for various locking scenarios:
**Etag, LockType, LockTimeout,  LockDate, LockToken, LastLockUpdate**. These field are not related to versioning rather than "checkout" feature. We are not using these fields (yet).

The mentioned **LastLockDate** is not part of the SenseNet. There is no database field and any item in the code with this name. LastLockDate is maybe **LastLockUpdate**: this field can be used in the „live lock” technology. After a timeout the lock is automatically invalid (means: unlocked) except if the client updates the lock with the token on time. Interpretation is something like this:

```
LockedIsValid = (now < LockDate + timeout || now < LastLockUpdate + timeout)
```